# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'nodes'

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get this example working;

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/2966094/46279db71d3c218664f72e1d3cb74cb2fb46da43/

The example online works perfectly. But when I copy the example to my local MAMP installation, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'nodes'.
```

My json is loading correctly, does anyone know where this problem is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did the following:

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/2966094.git pedigree_tree
cd pedigree_tree
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

... and then opened my browser to:

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

The example works without any problems, which is to be expected.

Perhaps you could try replicating my steps (you should have Python on your Mac). If it works via the python SimpleHTTPServer, the assumption would be that something is awry with your MAMP configuration.

Alternatively, perhaps something went wrong with your download / clone of the example. Do you see any errors in your browser developer console (in Chrome: Menu | Tools | Developer Tools)?

Comment: Really stupid mistake on my behalf, I had a template rendering plugin om my MAMP installation which parsed the javascript arrays a values.

Comment: I'm glad you could fix it, and thanks for selecting my attempt as the answer! :)