# D3 Visualization Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'nodes'

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I got the data response from Node.js and using jQuery to parse the returned object.  The code is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click( function() {
            $.get("./search?query="+ $("#query").val() + "&type=tree", function(data, status) {
                var article = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var res = article.ts;
                drawTree(res);
            });
        });
    });


function drawTree(data) {

    var w = 1280 - 80,
        h = 800 - 180,
        x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
        color = d3.scale.category20c(),
        root,
        node;

    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .round(false)
        .size([w, h])
        .sticky(true)
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

    var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("div")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .style("width", w + "px")
        .style("height", h + "px")
      .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");

    console.log(data);
    alert(data);

      node = root = data;

      var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
          .filter(function(d) { 
              return !d.children; 
        });

      var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
          .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "cell")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
          .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

      cell.append("svg:rect")
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

      cell.append("svg:text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

      d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

      d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
        treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
        zoom(node);
      });
    }

    function size(d) {
      return d.size;
    }

    function count(d) {
      return 1;
    }

    function zoom(d) {
      var kx = w / d.dx, ky = h / d.dy;
      x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
      y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

      var t = svg.selectAll("g.cell").transition()
          .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

      t.select("rect")
          .attr("width", function(d) { return kx * d.dx - 1; })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return ky * d.dy - 1; })

      t.select("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return kx * d.dx / 2; })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return ky * d.dy / 2; })
          .style("opacity", function(d) { return kx * d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

      node = d;
      d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Finally convert the object to be a JSON object as

```
var data = {
                 "name": "flare",
                 "children": [
                  {
                   "name": "analytics",
                   "children": [
                    {
                     "name": "cluster",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "graph",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
                      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
                      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
                      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
                      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "optimization",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
                     ]
                    }
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "animate",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
                    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
                    {
                     "name": "interpolate",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
                      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
                      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
                      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
                      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
                      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
                      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
                      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
                      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
                    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
                    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
                    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
                    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
                    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
                    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
                    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
                    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "data",
                   "children": [
                    {
                     "name": "converters",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
                      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
                      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
                      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
                      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
                    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
                    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
                    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
                    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
                    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "display",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
                    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
                    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
                    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "flex",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "physics",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
                    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
                    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
                    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
                    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
                    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
                    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
                    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "query",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
                    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
                    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
                    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
                    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
                    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
                    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
                    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
                    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
                    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
                    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
                    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
                    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
                    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
                    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
                    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
                    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
                    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
                    {
                     "name": "methods",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
                      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
                      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
                      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
                      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
                      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
                      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
                      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
                      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
                      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
                      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
                      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
                      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
                      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
                      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
                      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
                      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
                      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
                      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
                      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
                      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
                      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
                      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
                      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
                      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
                      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
                      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
                      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
                      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
                      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
                      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
                      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
                    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
                    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
                    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
                    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
                    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
                    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
                    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
                    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
                    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "scale",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
                    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
                    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
                    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
                    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
                    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
                    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
                    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
                    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
                    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "util",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
                    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
                    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
                    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
                    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
                    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
                    {
                     "name": "heap",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
                      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
                    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
                    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
                    {
                     "name": "math",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
                      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
                      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
                    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
                    {
                     "name": "palette",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
                      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
                      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
                      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
                    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
                    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
                    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
                    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
                   ]
                  },
                  {
                   "name": "vis",
                   "children": [
                    {
                     "name": "axis",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
                      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
                      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
                      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
                      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "controls",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
                      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
                      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
                      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
                      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
                      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
                      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
                      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
                      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
                      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
                      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "data",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
                      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
                      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
                      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
                      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
                      {
                       "name": "render",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
                       ]
                      },
                      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
                      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
                      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "events",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
                      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
                      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
                      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "legend",
                     "children": [
                      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
                      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
                      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
                     ]
                    },
                    {
                     "name": "operator",
                     "children": [
                      {
                       "name": "distortion",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
                       ]
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "encoder",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
                       ]
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "filter",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
                       ]
                      },
                      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
                      {
                       "name": "label",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
                       ]
                      },
                      {
                       "name": "layout",
                       "children": [
                        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
                       ]
                      },
                      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
                      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
                      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
                      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
                      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
                     ]
                    },
                    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
                   ]
                  }
                 ]
                };
```

However, it always generated a error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'nodes'.  How can I solve it?

Comment: Shooting in the dark since I cannot replicate the environment, but in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184930/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-array-has-no-method-nodes) the problem was that an unspecting plugin parsed the javascript arrays as values. Could the line `var res = article.ts;` be the problem?

Comment: I agree that there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you posted.  [Turning it into a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/j3448/1/) the only problem I had was that the zoom functions were referencing width and height variables outside of their scope -- the treemap `.nodes()` function works fine. Something in your work process must be chewing up the code...